# How can I do Image Upscaling (increase resolution) with Sharp?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, sharp

I have a digital image for which I want to increase its resolution using Sharp. For now all I have is

```
let image = sharp("image_path").resize({width:1200, height:1200});
```

However, this seems to only increase the size but not the quality. How can I increase the resolution of an image using Sharp?

Comment: _what do you see_? show us the results. -- where is the quality supposed to come from? you might want to read about "interpolation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling